Show hide Shapes based on cell value in vba
I have 20 shapes in my ** Active sheet**.
There names are following Item-1, Item-2, Item-3, . . . . . . . . till Item-20.
And a sheet6 or which sheet name is ITEM has item names in Range F2:F21.
Below VBA code is working fine.
But the code is too much long.
I have no idea how to make this code smaller?
Private Sub Group_1()
On Error Resume Next

    If Sheet6.Range("F2").Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-1").Visible = False
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-1").Visible = True
    End If
    
    If Sheet6.Range("F3").Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-2").Visible = False
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-2").Visible = True
    End If
    
    If Sheet6.Range("F4").Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-3").Visible = False
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-3").Visible = True
    End If
    
    If Sheet6.Range("F5").Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-4").Visible = False
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-4").Visible = True
    End If

    ' And So On till Item-20

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-1")).Select
    Selection.Formula = "=ITEM!F2"
    Range("A1").Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-2")).Select
    Selection.Formula = "=ITEM!F3"
    Range("A1").Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-3")).Select
    Selection.Formula = "=ITEM!F4"
    Range("A1").Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-4")).Select
    Selection.Formula = "=ITEM!F5"
    Range("A1").Select
' And so on till Item-20
End Sub

When I run this above code. It inserts Cell contents to My shapes From the Range Sheet6.Range("F2:F21") or Sheets("ITEM").Range("F2:F21").
But, if a cell F2 from Sheet6 is empty then Shape Item-1 from my ActiveSheet must be hidden. if a cell F3 from sheet6 is empty then Shape Item-2 must be hidden. and so on.

Please help and guide.


How familiar are you with loops?

Sir, I am a newbie.

Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.

@taller , Sir, I think I deleted that line (On Error Resume Next). and then I found that error line (ActiveSheet.Range("Item-" & i).Visible = IsEmpty(.Range("F" & i + 1).Value).

Why don't you know the name or code name of the active sheet? You are selecting a shape, writing a formula to it, and then selecting a cell. That doesn't seem right. Do you want to perform the operations in the second part of your code on all the shapes or just the visible ones? Please clarify by editing your post.

WE should avoid selecting Objects (Cells, Sheets, Shapes, ...ect.) whenever possible.
Watch: Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)
Private Sub Group_1()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim Cell As Range

    Rem Target range: Sheet6, starting at F2, resizing for 20 rows
    With Sheet6.Range("F2").Resize(20)
        For n = 1 To 20
            Rem Set the current cell in the range (F2:F21)
            Set Cell = .Cells(n, 1)

            Rem Attempt to set the shape named "Item-n"
            Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-" & n)

            Rem Check if the shape exists (sh is not Nothing)
            If Not sh Is Nothing Then
                Rem Set shape visibility based on whether the cell has content
                Rem This works because 0 evaluates as FALSE and any otehr value TRUE
                sh.Visible = Len(Cell.Value)
                
                Rem Set the shape formula to link with the corresponding cell
                sh.OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=ITEM!" & Cell.Address(0, 0)
            Else
                Rem If the shape is not found, print a debug message
                Debug.Print "Shape 'Item-" & n & "' not found."
            End If

            Rem Reset error handling
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next n
    End With
End Sub


Try this:
Option Explicit
Private Sub Group_1()
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim i As Long
     
    With Sheet6
    
        For i = 1 To 20
            
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Item-" & i).Visible = Not IsEmpty(.Range("F" & i + 1))
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-2")).Select
            Selection.Formula = "=ITEM!F" & i + 1
            Range("A1").Select
            
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub


Run-Time Error 1004. Application-define or object-define error. at line ActiveSheet.Range("Item-" & i).Visible = IsEmpty(.Range("F" & i + 1).Value).

@PrabhatVishwas Sorry, try it again. Had a typo.

the first line error resolved. but It is working in reverse. What was to be hidden is being shown, and what was to be shown is being hidden. and now Run-time error "438" Object doesn't support this property or method in line (ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-" & i)).Formula = "=ITEM!F" & i + 1). Sorry for my poor English. Google Translated.

@PrabhatVishwas No problem, try once more!

I think, We have to write ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-" & i)).Select in place of ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Item-2")).Select. Thank You Mr. @dwirony . You made my night. You answer was too much close of my question.
